# Fibrewise characterization of projectives

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module

This is exercise $20.13$ in Eisenbud. I ask a subproblem of it.

For $R$ a reduced a ring and $M$ a finitely generated projective $R$-module show:

The function $\mu_M(P)=\dim_{R_P/PR_P}(M_P/PM_P)$ is locally constant on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

It is not hard to prove this assuming $M$ is finitely presented.  How to do it in a general case.

Comment: What do you mean by "general case"? It's trivial to show that f.g. + projective implies finitely presented.

Comment: I just want a proof of that fact.

Comment: Indeed. I was unaware of this fact. I think my question is irrelevant now.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172254/finitely-generated-projective-finitely-presented-flat-over-a-noncommutative-no